# how to parametrize dependencies in Pytest

Tags: python, pytest

Let's say that there are two strings to test: "foo" and "bar", and for each string there is one ore more corresponding lists, e.g. for "foo" -> list1, list2, ... and for "bar" -> list3, list4, ... . How should the parametrize decorator be filled?

Comment: Please explain more. Give us a test function and explain what you want it to do. Tell us if you've tried something too...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would pass in the parameters as follows:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize("foo, bar", [
    (list1, list2),
    (list3, list4)])
def test_xxx():
    ...
```

You can use [this](https://github.com/shanefontaine/uniswap-python/blob/master/tests/test_uniswap.py#L116-L125) code as an example.